Laravel database connection using IBM DB2 - PDOException: USERNAME AND/OR PASSWORD INVALID
As the title says, im trying to create a connection to a IBM DB2 database using Laravel. Apparently the error is generated by having an invalid username/password, however, when I input the same username/password into DBeaver to check if it's correct, it connects without trouble.
I use a POST method with Postman to check the connection, and this is the first line I get in the Error Report: PDOException: SQLSTATE=08001, SQLDriverConnect: -30082 [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason &quot;24&quot; (&quot;USERNAME AND/OR PASSWORD INVALID&quot;).  SQLSTATE=08001
I have the exact same data in the database.php file and in the .env file, like this.
database.php
'ibm_db2' => [
            'driver' => 'db2_ibmi_ibm',
            // or 'db2_ibmi_ibm' / 'db2_zos_odbc' / 'db2_expressc_odbc / 'db2_ibmi_odbc'
            'driverName' => '{IBM i Access ODBC Driver}',
            // or '{iSeries Access ODBC Driver}' / '{IBM i Access ODBC Driver 64-bit}'
            'host' => '173.24.3.21',
            'username' => 'username1',
            'password' => 'supercoolPassword3D7E=AG`:6c',
            'database' => 'database1',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'default schema',
            'port' => 50003,
            'date_format' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
            // or 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u' / 'Y-m-d-H.i.s.u'...
            'odbc_keywords' => [
                'SIGNON' => 3,
                'SSL' => 0,
                'CommitMode' => 2,
                'ConnectionType' => 0,
                'DefaultLibraries' => '',
                'Naming' => 0,
                'UNICODESQL' => 0,
                'DateFormat' => 5,
                'DateSeperator' => 0,
                'Decimal' => 0,
                'TimeFormat' => 0,
                'TimeSeparator' => 0,
                'TimestampFormat' => 0,
                'ConvertDateTimeToChar' => 0,
                'BLOCKFETCH' => 1,
                'BlockSizeKB' => 32,
                'AllowDataCompression' => 1,
                'CONCURRENCY' => 0,
                'LAZYCLOSE' => 0,
                'MaxFieldLength' => 15360,
                'PREFETCH' => 0,
                'QUERYTIMEOUT' => 1,
                'DefaultPkgLibrary' => 'QGPL',
                'DefaultPackage' => 'A /DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0',
                'ExtendedDynamic' => 0,
                'QAQQINILibrary' => '',
                'SQDIAGCODE' => '',
                'LANGUAGEID' => 'ENU',
                'SORTTABLE' => '',
                'SortSequence' => 0,
                'SORTWEIGHT' => 0,
                'AllowUnsupportedChar' => 0,
                'CCSID' => 819,
                'GRAPHIC' => 0,
                'ForceTranslation' => 0,
                'ALLOWPROCCALLS' => 0,
                'DB2SQLSTATES' => 0,
                'DEBUG' => 0,
                'TRUEAUTOCOMMIT' => 0,
                'CATALOGOPTIONS' => 3,
                'LibraryView' => 0,
                'ODBCRemarks' => 0,
                'SEARCHPATTERN' => 1,
                'TranslationDLL' => '',
                'TranslationOption' => 0,
                'MAXTRACESIZE' => 0,
                'MultipleTraceFiles' => 1,
                'TRACE' => 0,
                'TRACEFILENAME' => '',
                'ExtendedColInfo' => 0,
            ],
            'options' => [
                PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_LOWER,
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false
            ]
            // + (defined('PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_SYS_NAMING') ? [PDO::I5_ATTI5_ATTR_DBC_SYS_NAMINGR_COMMIT => false] : [])
            // + (defined('PDO::I5_ATTR_COMMIT') ? [PDO::I5_ATTR_COMMIT => PDO::I5_TXN_NO_COMMIT] : [])
            // + (defined('PDO::I5_ATTR_JOB_SORT') ? [PDO::I5_ATTR_JOB_SORT => false] : [])
            // + (defined('PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_LIBL') ? [PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_LIBL => ''] : [])
            // + (defined('PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_CURLIB') ? [PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_CURLIB => ''] : [])
        ],

.env
DB_CONNECTION=ibm_db2
DB_HOST=173.24.3.21
DB_PORT=50003
DB_DATABASE=database1
DB_USERNAME=username1
DB_PASSWORD="supercoolPassword3D7E=AG`:6c"

Laravel doesn't really seem to take into consideration the .env file however, since changing stuff there doesn't do much, but changing stuff in the database.php file does indeed generate different errors.
Any idea on what to try? Thanks

Misconfigured. Your database.php seems to specify the IBM I access odbc driver, but the exception is reported from clidriver instead, a different driver.

@mao Right, is there anywhere I could check for it? It's definitely not a missing driver mistake since I made sure to download them and they show as active, but I dont know where to check

Stackoverflow is for programming questions, not simple config. Check phoinfo() for other .ini files, and sanity check the contents re drivers to use for pho
